# Don't allow empty textbox in asp.net mvc 3.1

Tags: javascript, c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I've got 2 HTML input textbox: "Email" and "Password". Whenever I submit these textboxes with no value I get this SQL exception: **SqlException: The parameterized query '(@email nvarchar(4000),@password nvarchar(4000))SELECT Email,Pas' expects the parameter '@email', which was not supplied.**

I just want an message that says that I need to fill in a email and password. I've already an JS function that checks these textboxes for empty value and it works. But it still redirects to the SQL Exception page afterwards. I think I've done something stupid with my database properties. How can I fix this?

```
            string sqlquery = "SELECT Email,Password FROM [dbo].[User] WHERE Email = @email and Password = @password;";
            SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
            sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", user.Email);
            sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", user.Password);
            SqlDataReader sdr = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader();
            if (sdr.Read())
            {

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewData["Message"] = "Fout";
            }
            sqlconn.Close();



          return View();
```

## Login

```
<form asp-action="Login" method="post">
    <input  id="loginEmail" type="text" name="Email" asp-for="@Model.Email" />
    <input id="loginWachtwoord" type="password" name="Password" asp-for="@Model.Password" />
    <input type="submit" onclick="CheckNullOrEmpty()" value="Login" />
    <h1>@Html.ViewData["Message"]</h1>

</form>
```

Comment: theres many ways to validate things. how is `user.Email` getting getting filled.

Comment: <form asp-action="Login" method="post">
        <input  id="loginEmail" type="text" name="Email" asp-for="@Model.Email" /> </form

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @DanielA.White these ar all the codes I've got for the log in system. I've got an Model "User" that has the properties Email and Password.

Comment: Please don't store users' passwords in plain text in your database; use hashing. https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just check the parameters before you try to query the database

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Email) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Password)) {
    ViewData["Message"] = "Fout";
    return View();
}
//... validate first then try to create the statement.
```

You could also try/catch the errors and return the View in the catch block if you don't want the error page popping up. There's also [ModelState.IsValid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api) which you can read about